# Select all soft deleted item which owner is not soft delete in Eloquent / Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query to get all soft delete tournaments:

```
 $tournaments = Tournament::onlyTrashed();
```

Thing is Tournament model has a FK owner_id.

Sometimes, owner has been soft deleted, so when I try to get $tournament->owner->id, I get an exception.

How to get All trashed Tournament which user is not soft deleted in Eloquent???

Is there a more elegant (Eloquent) solution that :

```
 $tournaments = Tournament::onlyTrashed()
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tournament.user_id')
            ->where('users.deleted_at', '=', null)
            ->select('tournament.*')
            ->get();
```

Tx!

Comment: Have you tried `has('Owner')`?

Comment: you rock! it works! Please put it as answer! I love eloquent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has` and `whereHas` (for more complex relationship requirements) can be used to limit results to records that have an active relationship.

```
Tournament::has('Owner')
```

will select only tournaments with a valid (existing and non-soft-deleted) Owner.

Comment: do you know eloquent tutorials more than official docs and laracasts?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Laracasts is pretty much the gold standard.